# When to add fresh ginger?

Tags: techniques, spices

I am considering brewing an Amber ale with a bit of ginger in it, but I don't know whether I should treat it more like a spice and steep/boil it, or more like fruit, and rack onto the ginger for a week or two of secondary fermentation.    Should I use a combination of the two?   What has worked for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ginger works a little bit like hops - if you boil it longer, it adds a different spiciness than if you add it at flameout or in secondary.  Boil a couple ounces of ginger on the stove and you can see what I mean.  The aromatics tend to leave, but there is a residual heat.

I've had success by adding it in stages as if it were a hop - a big dose early, and smaller additions later in the boil.

Comment: Good answer.  I also put a dose in the secondary for a little extra ginger flavor and aroma without too much bite.

Answer (score 4):

I add fresh ginger the last 5 min. of the boil.  I've been pleased with the results.

Comment: Same here, works great for me.  Upvote.