# How much ginger should be used at what point of the process?

Tags: additives, ginger

What is a reasonable amount of fresh ginger to use to lightly flavor a beer? Does the quantity to use differ based on when it is added in the process (boil vs flame out vs secondary)?

I realize "*lightly*" is a rather subjective term but I'm just trying to say that the ginger flavor should not be the primary taste.

Comment: Slightly similar to http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2798/when-to-add-fresh-ginger

Answer (score 3):

Based purely on personal experiance I would say ~200g of boiled ginger per 23L will give a light background taste. I use ~1kg to make it the most prominent taste (like the ginger cider I brewed last weekend).